# Given $(X,Y)$ a Gaussian random vector, find the properties of $(X-Y,X+Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}(\det \Sigma)^{1/2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\vec x - \vec \mu)^{T}\Sigma^{-1}(\vec x - \vec\mu)}$, I want to find $\vec\mu$ and $\Sigma$ of $(U,V)=(X-Y,X+Y)$.

First, I know $(U,V)$ is a Gaussian because it is a multiplication of $(X,Y)$ by an invertible matrix.

To find $f_{U,V}$ I devided $f_{X,Y}$ by the Jacobian $\frac {\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}$ which is $2$.

Before I continue, I wanted to check whether my plan is good- replace $x$ and $y$ in the power of $e$ by $x=\frac{u+v}2$ and $y=\frac{v-u}2$, then order and find everything from scratch, hoping things will fall nicely into place (for example, I am worried the $C$ won't come out as $\frac {1} {(2\pi)^{n/2}(\det \Sigma)^{1/2}}$ for the new $\Sigma$, after the devision by $2$ and all the other manipulations).

Or, is there a nice way to derive the new $\vec\mu$ and $\Sigma$ from the old ones?

Also, I need to find $P(X\geq Y)$. Here I planned to find $P(U\geq 0)$ by double integration of $f_{U,V}$. Again, lots of work. Any nicer way of doing that?

Comment: Shortcut: As you said, $(U,V)^T=A(X,Y)^T$ and this alone implies that the mean is $A\vec\mu$ and the covariance matrix is $A\Sigma A^T$, end of story. Second question: Identify the mean $\mu_U$ and variance $\sigma^2_U$ of $U$ and deduce that $P(X\geqslant Y)=P(U\geqslant0)=P(\mu_U+Z\sigma_U\geqslant0)=P(Z\geqslant-\mu_U/\sigma_U)=\Phi(\mu_U/\sigma_U)$ where $Z$ is standard normal with CDF $\Phi$.

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Did Now I noticed- in the last part, isn't it $1-\Phi$?

Comment: No it isn't. Please review the definition of $\Phi$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left(\begin{array}{c}
U\\
V\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & -1\\
1 & 1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
X\\
Y\end{array}\right)$

so for $A:=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & -1\\
1 & 1\end{array}\right)$ the random vector has normal distribution with $A\mu$ as expectation
and $A\Sigma A^{T}$ as convariance matrix.

Comment: Wow: answer accepted in less than 20 seconds... Not sure this is a healthy way to use the site.

Comment: @Did Yes, you are right. I repaired.

Comment: A more elegant way has been reached to you in the comment of @Did. Do you understand it?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't see it when I commented here